# When viewing my twitter bootstrap site on a mobile a 20px gutter is added on the sides. How do I stop this?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When viewing my twitter bootstrap website on a mobile there are 20px gutters on each side. This stops any content that touches the edges on the desktop from doing so on the mobile. The twitter bootstrap homepage itself doesn't have these gutters when viewed on mobile. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Other websites say putting a body {padding-left:0;padding-right:0} helps but this creates another problem of messing up the navbar.

Any clues?

Comment: Can we have a link or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Yep it's at http://www.lynsrecipes.com/

Answer (score 7):

Try adding this CSS somewhere *after* the Bootstrap CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom,
  .navbar-static-top {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: @shim You're welcome! Please mark this answer as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer did not solve the same issue for me...but did lead me to my own solution

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    body {
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

with out position:absolute; on the body tag I end up with a huge gutter on the right hand side of the document on small screens such as the iPhone.  But when I add position:absolute; to the body tag I get the same gutter on large desktop screens.  Putting it in the above media query solves it for me.

I would welcome an explanation for why this is happening.

I am using bootstrap 3.0 final